# Duplicate symbol 'WixComponentGroup:<any>' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated

Tags: c#, xml, wix

Currently for my Requirement I want a component group to be placed on two different directories during installation  for example
**MyComponet.wxs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Include>
  <ComponentGroup Id="Sim_SI">

    <ComponentRef Id="Component1" />
    <ComponentRef Id="Component2" />
enter code here
    <!-- Add more component references as needed -->
  </ComponentGroup>
</Include>
```

and I want to use this wxs into another wxs file in two different directories like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <?define SourceDir="..\..\_Out\Release" ?>
  <?define AnotherSourceDir="..\..\_Out\Release\Executor" ?>

  <!-- Define preprocessor variables for component IDs and directories -->
  <?define ComponentId1="COMPONENT_ID_1"?>
  <?define ComponentId2="COMPONENT_ID_2"?>
  <?define Directory1="INSTALLFOLDER"?>
  <?define Directory2="ANOTHERFOLDER"?>

  <Module Id="Merge.Base" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="COMPONENT_ID_1"/>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Sim_SI" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="COMPONENT_ID_2"/>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="[BinaryFolder]" >
                <Directory Id="ANOTHERFOLDER" Name="Executor" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

    <!-- ... Add more features and components as needed ... -->
  </Module>
    <?include $(var.SourceDir)\MyComponent.wxi?>
    <?include $(var.AnotherSourceDir)\MyComponent.wxi?>
   <!-- Include MyComponent.wxi and set the preprocessor variables -->
    <?include $(var.SourceDir)\MyComponent.wxi ?>
    <?define ComponentId=$(var.ComponentId1)?>
    <?define Directory=$(var.Directory1)?>
    <?include $(var.AnotherSourceDir)\MyComponent.wxi ?>
    <?define ComponentId=$(var.ComponentId2)?>
    <?define Directory=$(var.Directory2)?>
</Wix>
```

so how can we use a single component group in two different directories in a single wxs file ?

Comment: You can't have the same variable Directory with two different values at the same time.

Comment: Hi @jdweng thanks for your response, but  is there any way we can install a component Group (Ex; **<ComponentRef Id="Sim_SI" />**) in two different directories ex **<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="[BinaryFolder]" > ** and  **<Directory Id="ANOTHERFOLDER" Name="Executor" />**